# Python: return dict from class method to main()

Tags: python, class, methods, return

I'm baffled and unable to express proper googlefu in figuring this out. I am using argparse to try and take CLI args to make a dictionary. How do I get jdict returned from the class? or callable so that I can append it to another dict and write to a file? I'm looking to avoid laying the rest of the code (reading json file, appending new dict, writing file)

```
class MakeData:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

    # Args taken, make dict with
    def makejson(self):
        self.jdict = {
            "key1": self.args.srv[0],
            "key2": self.args.srv[1],
            "key3": self.args.srv[2]
        }
        return self.jdict

def main():
    args = get_args()
    s = MakeData(args)
    s.makejson()

    # want to print jdict here, made from above class method
    print jdict
```

Comment: assign the result of the method to a variable?

Comment: just  `print s.makejson()` or `jdict = s.makejson(); print jdict`

Comment: @pythduc See the [Python tutorial: Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), in particular [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the jdict in the code shown. You are just not using a variable to store it.

```
jdict = s.makejson()
print jdict
```

Or, simply,

```
print s.jdict
```

will also work.. Which means the returning of the variable is not necessary

Comment: Aha! s.jdict was what I was looking for. For some reason I thought I needed to specific the class, then method as s.MakeData.makejson.

Comment: @pythduc: Glad it helped :) Feel free to accept my answer if it was of use

Comment: accessing `s.jdict` won't it break oop's rule?
pardon me if I'm wrong, I'm c++ background.

Comment: @Mayur which OOPS rule are you talking about here? jdict is not a private variable (which starts with an `_`)

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: It's about encapsulation. All members should be in a single unit but by accessing `jdict` outside of class aren't we violating encapsulation?